# How to get current data rate or available bandwidth value in NS-3 or DCE-NS-3?

Tags: c++, ns-3, ad-hoc-network

I am trying to get the current data rate or available bandwidth on each Wi-Fi Interface in DCE-NS-3 or NS-3. I have two mobile nodes in Wi-Fi Adhoc mode, with IEEE 802.11b and g standards. The bandwidth that I am setting is 11 Mbps and 54 Mbps. But when using the iperf application in dce-ns3, with UDP mode, the data transfer rate for 11Mbps is 1.31 Mbytes and for 54 Mbps it is 6.46 MBytes constant always.

I can get the static value which is never changed, through GetBitRate() method of DataRate class, but I need the available bandwidth or data rate, periodically as due to data transfer of other layer packets, the available bandwidth or data rate on each wireless interface will be changing continuously.

Hence, I am looking for the proper method to be able to get the current data rate or available data rate during my simulation (at runtime) whenever I want to transfer the data using my scheduling mechanism.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question, so just to be sure that you didn't mix up your units. 1.31 MB (10.48 Mb) are very close to 11 Mb, same with 6.46 MB (51.68 Mb) to 54 Mb.

Comment: Yes, they are same, the question is, how can I have different data rate or available bandwidth instead of these same values?